# How to specify string delimiter using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string `'w_600,h_600/c_overlay:{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_image},g_center,y_-157,x_0/c_overlay:{c_crop,w_300,h_300/main_image}/FFFFFF'`.

I want to split the string by `/`, however, I want to use as a delimiter only `/` that are not inside `{...}`.

So the result after splitting the string would be:

`['w_600,h_600', 'c_overlay{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_image},g_center,y_-157,x_0', 'c_overlay:{c_crop,w_300,h_300/main_image}', 'FFFFFF']`

I tried to use `.split(/(?<!{.*?)\/|(?<=}.*?)\//)` but it works incorrectly if there is more than one `{...}`.

```js
console.log('w_600,h_600/c_overlay:{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_image},g_center,y_-157,x_0/c_overlay:{c_crop,w_300,h_300/main_image}/FFFFFF'.split(/(?<!{.*?)\/|(?<=}.*?)\//))
```

Comment: The best way is to not use split. Match like

Comment: `(?:[^/{}]+|(?:{.*?})|[{}])+(?=/)|(?<=/)(?:[^/{}]+|(?:{.*?})|[{}])`

https://regex101.com/r/9OiL9y/1

Comment: ... approach with a positive lookahead ... [`/\/(?=(?:[^}]+\{)|(?:[^}{]+$)|$)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/HYRvIM/1) ... which features three OR combined patterns in order to match/cover any possible delimiter occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a regex approach, but you could do it with a function like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwA4BsZQPJgCpwDWApmNiFMjACbHaqkDC6cyxiAFDGKhQFwooAJ24BzADQoMWAiTADkwsZLgN8RUgqVgJiCCzazNgkToCUW06IDaAXUQBvAFCJE6YlERhiisYzjgngC8iAAMANwubh56IEJCpMGIAOTJka4QCIqICcgg6FCWYnaIIXaRUcBwQpyZYNngWIhwwIjcvFBmjlGuMK0cjcFBIaqkRmBd3r46-oGIANQhAIzprojE6Gxt-YOlw3oGxOOTPrAzAWCeALTLq707YE0AhPtomFDjiAA+X16nfhdPAA+MJdZxrNYQOIJS4LEKDO6QhBnEDEREAXx6OR8+SgADpeMgABYcKHxRJmRFkmFJVKrTFRPq1aGJPHuHRQImIEGhLq5XEEkDE0ksy6UqIJKBxJD8gqRBl1bLtCilRAAAwA7gB9ABsoVC4iJuv1AHoIFq4AA3YhCdAAQwAnnwHObgFhxNqAKwAdgNRoATJ6dWatRAhKoPca-VGTQBbO3cLUweOiYjo8SiUOJG3iB1aq5LH3iAAeWtCIatNvtTpdofDqEjAGZ9Yatc3y-HE8m7an0SaAGKDodqiqKzyypJvLC4cbkSg0OhqZisYhcHgUSTJE3JTcOHcpdHJcWKuDuNlwUQcCfioA)

```js
function splitOnTokenOutsideOpenClose (input, splitToken, openToken, closeToken) {
  let nestingCount = 0;
  let current = '';
  const result = [];

  for (const unit of input) {
    if (unit === openToken) nestingCount += 1;
    else if (unit === closeToken) nestingCount -= 1;
    if (unit !== splitToken || nestingCount > 0) {
      current += unit;
      continue;
    }
    result.push(current);
    current = '';
  }

  if (current.length > 0) result.push(current);
  return result;
}

const input = `w_600,h_600/c_overlay:{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_image},g_center,y_-157,x_0/c_overlay:{c_crop,w_300,h_300/main_image}/FFFFFF`;

const result = splitOnTokenOutsideOpenClose(input, '/', '{', '}');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment ...

> *... approach with a positive lookahead ... [`/\/(?=(?:[^}]+\{)|(?:[^}{]+$)|$)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/HYRvIM/1) ... which features three OR combined patterns in order to match/cover any possible delimiter occurrence.*

**Edit** according to *The fourth bird*`s suggestion

The above pattern can be shortened to ...[`\/(?=[^}]+{|[^}{]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/HYRvIM/2)

```js
// // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/HYRvIM/1]
// const regXSplit = /\/(?=(?:[^}]+\{)|(?:[^}{]+$)|$)/g;

// changed according to "The fourth bird"'s suggestion
// 
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/HYRvIM/2]
const regXSplit = /\/(?=[^}]+{|[^}{]*$)/g;

console.log(
  'w_600,h_600/c_overlay:{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_image},g_center,y_-157,x_0/c_overlay:{c_crop,w_300,h_300/main_image}/FFFFFF'
    .split(regXSplit)
);
console.log(
  'w_600,h_600/c_overlay:{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_image},g_center,y_-157,x_0/c_overlay:{c_crop,w_300,h_300/main_image}/FFFFFF/'
    .split(regXSplit)
);
console.log(
  'w_600,h_600/c_overlay:{c_fit,w_570,h_256/c_crop,w_600,h_600/main_im/age},g_center/,y_-157,x_0/c_overlay:{c_crop,w_/300,h_300/main_image}/FFF/FFF/'
    .split(regXSplit)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You might shorten the pattern to `\/(?=[^}]+{|[^}{]*$)` as the non capture group by themselves have no extra purpose, and the last alternation can be removed for the end of the string if the quantifier for the second last is optional. See https://regex101.com/r/OGlyej/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird ... Thanks. Edited/improved according to your suggestion. Now, with looking at it, it's obvious.